# In web-application, is there any way to run a function at a specific time even if I am not on the webpage?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, meteor, jsx, digital-ocean

```
class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    seconds: moment().format('HHmmss'),
    turned: true,
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState(() => ({
      seconds: moment().format('HHmmss'),
    }));
    if (this.state.seconds >= '233000' && this.state.seconds <= '234000') { //make turned false between 23:30 - 23:40
      this.setState(() => ({
        turned: false,
      }));
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.submitToToday(), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

submitToToday() {
    if (this.state.seconds >= '234500' && this.state.seconds <= '235500' && this.state.turned === false) {
      // HERE MongoDB update that I want to run
      this.setState(() => ({
        turned: true,
      }));
    }
  }
```

In this code, I set to run the function "submitToToday()" once between 23:45 - 23:55.

This works fine when I am on the webpage but this would do nothing when I am not on the webpage. Is there any way that I can run the code even if I am not on the webpage?

Or, is it possible to make the hosting service just open the webpage? I am using DigitalOcean.

Comment: This is React code, which suggests it runs in the client's browser. In that case, you cannot just arbitrarily run code in the user's browser at a random time when they're not on your site. However, you could implement a backend with a server you control that runs scripts at any time you want.

Comment: You will require back end for this i suppose because the react code will only work if the browser window is open.

Comment: Can I assume the User has entered the Page at least once to initialize the routine? Or should the routine run totally Independent of visit and still inform the User about the result?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it is a DB operation as the comment suggest, the best way to do this would be in a CRON job. For Meteor just select one of the packages for CRON jobs that you like the most on Atmosphere: https://atmospherejs.com/?q=cron
After that you can call a Meteor method which is going to create a new entry in the CRON to run the given task at the given time.